# online visualizer for dual primal in 2D plane

Tags: linear-programming

Is there an online app that helps visualize the following: I can specify several lines in 2D plane which defines the inequalities and I will give a direction which specifies the objective. Thus this is a complete LP primal problem. And then the app automatically visualizes the dual feasible region and dual objective direction in another 2D plot.

Comment: Does [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) meet your requirements?